# Print empty map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a map to add values from iterating a text file.
Inside the loop to read the txt file the map is not empty. 
But outside from the loop the map is returning empty.

```
function processTxt(inputFile) {

    var instream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile),
        outstream = new (require('stream'))(),
        rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

    var myMap  = new Map();


    rl.on('line', function (line) {
      var array = line.split(" ");

      if(line.startsWith("/")) {
        myMap.set(array[1], array[3];

      }

      //If I print the map here the map is not empty
      myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
           console.log(`${key} = ${value}`);
      }, myMap);

    });


    //The map outside the function here is returning empty.
    myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(`${key} = ${value}`);
    }, myMap);


    return myMap;
}
```

Comment: The callback is asynchronous and thus is executed after the map is returned. This function should be turned into promise and not resolving before ending reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the `map` before it's been loaded.  `rl.on` is an `async` function so it immediately continues to the next line (the `myMap.forEach...`).

Answer (score 0):

`readline.on` is an asynchronous function that sets up an event listener. The flow of your program is such that the `readline.on()` function call is put into the event loop and all your code that follows it happens first.

Check out this fantastic video on understanding the event loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ